# Rear or Front Facing Camera through EXIF Data?

Tags: metadata, cameraphones

I have compared the standard EXIF data from a picture taken with a mobile phone's rear camera and another taken with the same phone's front camera. The same fields appear in both files and no big difference jump out.

Is there a flag in the file or something similar in the EXIF data between rear and front pictures that could positively determine which camera took the picture?

Comment: The resolution often differs: the camera facing the user has a lower resolution than the camera on the back. Maybe that is a useful indicator?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke The focal length is probably more reliable than resolution, as long as you have a specimen of both to compare, and don't need a generic solution.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I ended up using resolution paired with make/model for an 60% solution.  I say 60% because various apps (and the user) can change the resolution so this is imperfect, but good enough for a rough sort.

Comment: @R3dChief, isn't the file size a **huge difference**? For me, the difference between front and back cam is usually 15x in filesize. E.g. 130kb vs 1800kb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution often differs: the camera facing the user has a lower resolution than the camera on the back.

A few examples I pulled from [gsmarena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?&idPhone1=6378&idPhone2=6033&idPhone3=7972):

- iPhone 6:                    Front 8MP;    Back 1.2MP
- Samsung Galaxy S5: Front 16MP;  Back 2MP
- Huawei P9:                Front 12MP;  Back 8MP

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for all phones, but a look at EXIF for the iPhone 5, I've noticed that the ***Lens*** data element tells you a fair bit:

- Rear camera: *iPhone 5 back camera 4.12mm f/2.4*
- Front camera: *iPhone 5 front camera 2.18mm f/2.4*

As I said, can't be sure for other phone makes, but that's a starting point for you and it's probably pretty consistent across the IOS family line.

Comment: I can confirm that files from my recent model Samsung *don't* have that nice lens field in EXIF, hence my suggestion of the focal length heuristic.